# KendoUI, Numeric format 12,123.33 to 12.123,33 €, on textbox and grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need show this format: 12.123,33 € for use it in Spain.
Change period (point) for thousands and comma for decimals.

In my code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kendo.culture.es-ES.js"></script>
```

The value of the decimal column (MySQL database) is: 12123.33

I tried with this code:

a)

```
$("#importe_oferta").kendoNumericTextBox({
culture: "es-ES"
format: "c2",
min: 0,
decimals: 2,
spinners: false
});
```

Result: 1.212.33.00 € ->wrong

b)

```
$("#importe_oferta").kendoNumericTextBox({
format: "c2",
min: 0,
decimals: 2,
spinners: false
```

});

Result: $12,123.33 ->wrong

c)

```
$("#importe_oferta").kendoNumericTextBox({
min: 0,
decimals: 2,
spinners: false
```

});

Result: 1,2123.43 ->wrong

And the same problem on the grid : 12,123.43 <-wrong

If anybody have the solution of this problem, please write a possible solution.
Thanks
Julio

Comment: Having the same issue, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some work-around like this one:

```
$("#percentage").kendoNumericTextBox({
              format: "{0:###########.########## $}",
                culture: "es-ES",
                min : 0,
                max: 0.1,
                step: 0.01
            });
```

Comment: thanks Petur! I think my problem is when I read the value from Mysql via PHP, the value is correct, only I need format the value for use it with kendo numeric format.